# No route matches {:controller=>"results", :action=>"show"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im upgrading a rails 2 app to rails 3 app and am having a bunch of routing issues. Heres the current:

So in the page its trying to load (results/_form.html.erb) I have a form with the following syntax:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "results",:action => "show") do %>
```

And i do have an action in my results_controller.rb called show. Yet i keep getting the no route matches error. Is this rails 2 syntax and not 3? Is there something I need to do in my routes.rb file? I think there is because that was a a major change between rails 2 and 3, im just not sure what. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

show action ideally should expect id to be passed in the params:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "results",:action => "show", :id => @user.id) do %>
```

Comment: Yeah but that cant be the cause of this problem

Comment: Correction! That was the problem! Sorry for doubting :)